# Models of infinite groups and 'Group-like' objects

Tags: logic, model-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group, and for simplicity, we will assume that $G$ is also countable. Now, with $G$ in mind, we construct a new language $L_G=\{f_{a_i\_},f_{\_a_i}:a_i\in G\}$ where $f_{a_i\_}(x)=a_ix$ and $f_{\_a_i}(x)=xa_i$ (Note that if $G$ is abelian, we can can restrict the language to $\{f_{\_a_i}:a_i \in G\}$) . Let $T=Th_{L_G}(G)$ (i.e. $T$ is the theory of G in the language $L_G$). It is clear that since $G$ is countable, $L$ is also countable. Therefore, $T$ is a countable, complete theory in a countable language. We say that $M$ is 'group-like' if $M\models T$ for some countably infinite group $G$.

Question 1: If $G$ is countably categorical in $L=\{1,\cdot\}$, then is $T$ countably categorical in $L_G$? (My suspicion is no).

Question 2: What do uncountable 'groups-like' models look like?

Question 3: Can anyone give me an example (countable or uncountable) of a model $M$ such that $M \models T$ but $M$ is "radically not a group" (I know that "radically not a group" is not well defined, but I think the intuition is clear).

Comment: $T$ is never countably categorical, for otherwise there would be finitely many $0$-definable sets in each arity. However if $a_1, a_2$ are different, then $\{(x, y) : f_{a_1}(x) = y\} \neq \{(x, y) : f_{a_2}(x) = y\}$ (and this is part of $T$).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but at a glance, I think that the models of your theory are exactly the disjoint unions of copies of $G$ *as two-sided $G$-spaces*. So the theory should be uncountably categorical (provided that the group is countable) and have countably infinitely many countable models (provided that the group is infinite). I'm not sure what you mean by "radically not a group", but I think you could give any model $M$ a group structure compatible with an extension of $G$ by a (any?) group of size $M/G$ (in a manner compatible with its $G$-space structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, by Levon Haykazyan's first comment, question 1 is answered in the negative.

From [this paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/People/pillay/lecturenotes_modeltheory.pdf), on page 14, we can answer questions 2 and 3.

Example 1.38 states, "Let $G$ be an infinite group of cardinality $\kappa$ say. Let $L = \{\lambda_g : g \in G\}$ where the $\lambda_g$ are unary function symbols. Let $T$ be the theory of free $G$-sets. Then $T$ is categorical in every cardinality $> \kappa$, and complete".

I think this is the fullest answer this question can possibly receive.